# How to override Stripe's event parameter in CLI

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been trying for hours now. I'm trying to trigger event locally, first I tried: `stripe trigger checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` and they I get error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "The payment method type provided: bacs_debit is invalid. Please ensure the provided type is activated in your dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings) and your account is enabled for any preview features that you are trying to use. See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options for supported payment method, currency, and country combinations.",
    "param": "payment_method_types",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Then I tried `stripe trigger checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded --override "checkout_session:payment_method_types[0]=card"` and then I got:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid request (check your POST parameters): unable to determine value for parameter: payment_method_types. For assistance, contact support at https://support.stripe.com/contact/.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/bacs-debit "This payment method is only available to Stripe accounts in the United Kingdom. You can create a new Stripe account in an eligible country to accept payments using this payment method." Is your Stripe account set as being in the UK?

Comment: Nope, in Croatia. This is just testing webhooks via CLI, there should not be any restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `bacs_debit` is the default for testing async_payment_succeeded. It is only available in UK, so if you are in different location, you are out of luck.

Even after a long search I haven't found a way to override the array, and if you use it as `--override "checkout_session:payment_method_types[]=card"`, that only appends it as second value, so `bacs_debit` will stay first and still trigger the error.

In the end I have removed the value first, then added a new one. I also had to override currency to EUR, as I wanted to test SEPA_DEBIT and that needs EUR, not default GBP:

```
stripe trigger checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded --override "price:currency=eur" --remove "checkout_session:payment_method_types" --override "checkout_session:payment_method_types[]"=sepa_debit
```

This one gets through, unfortunately the card used for payment is still VISA and the event triggered is checkout.session.completed , not the completed_async. Not sure what else to add, but maybe it helps someone to get further.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Stripe CLI can only trigger a subset of Event types. You can see an exhaustive list of supported Events via either:

1. running `stripe trigger --help` in the command line, or
2. the [CLI documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/trigger#trigger-event)

It looks like you can't trigger `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded`, only `checkout.session.completed` is supported.

Comment: I have  checkout.session.async_payment_failed in supported events